# Two interviews - how should I prepare

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search

I have two interviews this week for a Junior Full-Stack Developer position at two different companies.

The first company were good enough to let me know that the interview will be informal, nothing heavy, they will ask me mostly questions about my aspirations and tech path. This kinda made me feel more relaxed because I was studying really hard for the tech part.

The second company will probably give me tech test.  The tech stack is *slightly different* in both companies, but they *all share a common core*.

How do I prepare for both of these interviews? Should I study and be prepared only for the technologies that are similar to both companies, or should I push myself to understand a little bit each technology the company uses?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I prepare for both of these interviews?

In short, study hard, and **be as prepared as you can be**.  Focus on the technology stacks noted and do not go outside of that as then you potentially will be in over your head.  You should have a *base understanding of the technologies in question*.

> should I push myself to understand a little bit each technology the
>   company uses?

In short **yes**, *you should push yourself*.  One glaring weakness may not break the bank so to speak, but it won't help your cause.  I am a firm believer is putting your absolute best foot forward which would mean putting in as much time as you can on the technologies you are not familiar with.

Another pointer I will give to you:  Don't forget about the **other more soft aspects** of the interview.  If you nail the technical aspect, even non technical questions will matter.

Comment: Wish I could accept all of the comments. Valuable feedback, I appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

That's a lot of different tools. Some of them are pretty obscure. If there's one you've never worked with - I'd suggest getting your hands on it before the interview.  AWS in particular is pretty easy to practice beforehand. For $5, you can spin up a few servers and see how they connect together.

They won't (well, they *shouldn't*) expect you to be good at any of them - so long as you don't give them a blank stare.

If they ask you a question that you don't know, it's OK, but you want to be able to say "I don't know, but based on my understanding of the question, it's similar to this thing I *do* know."

Also - *junior* full stack developer? Either they want:

a senior developer at entry level pay - in which case the interview will suck, and you shouldn't let it get you down.

or an entry level dude who wants to learn, in which case they will care more about how you think than what you know.

Make sure to get a good night's sleep before the interview!

Answer (score 3):

> How do I prepare for both of these interviews? Should I study and be prepared only for the technologies that are similar to both companies, or should I push myself to understand a little bit each technology the company uses?

If you just study the technology they have in common you will be in trouble if asked about some specific piece of tech that is exclusive to one of the companies.

To be honest, I think that there is really no way to truly "study for an interview"; the idea of them is to *get a peek on what you already know* to see if you are a strong candidate.

Anyways, I suggest you become acquainted with all the technologies involved, or with most of them. Just be **careful not to fake it**; if you really don't know much about a specific tool it's better to be honest and say so (be sure to mention you know alternatives or experience with similar techs). If you don't this can come down at you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You are expected not to know. You are expected to compensate that with energy and enthusiasm. So trying to learn as much as you can from what they use is what you need to do